# Angular directives two way binding with Object look ups

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm passing in two bindings into a custom angular v1.4.3 directive.

1. An Object with 2way binding (model: '=') which can be an Array or not [{something: 'foo'}, {something: 'moo'}, ...] or just {something: 'foo', other: 'test'}
2. A look up for that model to use in that object (lookUp: '@'). It's string that describes the path to find the data I want to use in that directive. For example '[0].something' or '.something'.

I already created an function to use the string to get the data but it breaks the 2 way binding as any updates I make on that plucked data is separate from the bound model Object.

The function I'm using to find objects with a string key is:

```
Object.resolve = function (path, obj, safe) {
  return path.split('.').reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return !safe ? prev[curr] : (prev ? prev[curr] : undefined)
  }, obj || self)
}

vm.data = Object.resolve(vm.lookUp, vm.model); // finds the data I need to display and edit but breaks the binding to vm.model
```

Is than a more angular way to do this and keep the binding in tact?

Comment: Look into using an `$observe`  listener in your directive. [AngularJS $compile Directive Attributes API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes).

Answer (score 0):

1. Such function to retrieve object propery is already implemented - $parse.
2. To maintain bindings use $watch.

> ```
> app.directive('test', function($parse) {
>   return {
>     restrict : 'E',
>     scope : {
>       model : '=',
>       lookUp : '@'
>     },
>     template : 'Result is : {{result}}',
>     link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
>       function getResult() {
>         return $parse('model' + scope.lookUp)(scope);
>       }  
>       scope.$watch(getResult, function() {
>         scope.result = getResult();
>       });
>     }
>   }
> })
> ```

http://plnkr.co/edit/J5vlnGkHfwNYDZHO4lx6?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jm3KlZJImKxWvfcq7Zzo?p=preview  Two way binding is still broken.